# Entity–relationship model strange notation

Tags: uml, diagram

Find below attached an image of an UML diagram. The 1 and n sign define the relations between entities, right? What bothers me is the strange notation of the minuses and asterisk. What do those signs mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-1` and `-N` are actually the rolenames of the associations.

The multiplicity is defined on all roles as `*` which means **Zero or more**

The `-` before the rolename indicates **private** visibility.

It may not make much sense from a functional point of view, but I believe this is valid UML from a syntax view.

Comment: And what would be the sign to indicate a one or more multiplicity?

Comment: Zero or more = `*` or `0..*` - One or more = `1..*` - Exactly 1 = `1` or `1..1`